# Windows Phone: Why is this Style not being applied to the Button in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone

I am trying to understand why a Style is not being applied to the Button control in C#. I have found a simple way to reproduce this problem: off a new Blank App Template for Windows Phone in Visual Studio, add the following lines of code to the `MainPage.xaml`:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Name="TileStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Button x:Name="btn" Style="{StaticResource TileStyle}" />
```

When the app is run, the Button is borderless (as it should be). **However,** when you add this line of code to the `OnNavigatedTo` event handler in the code-behind file:

```
btn.Style = TileStyle;
```

When you run the app, the button is no longer borderless. Why is this?

Comment: Set a break point on the assignment and check that the value of the 'TileStyle' that is being assigned, has a value. Maybe it is assigning null and hence does not do as expected.

Comment: It works perfectly borderless here, is there something else you are doing ??

Comment: @PhilWright You may be right... I just checked by doing an `if (TileStyle == null)` test, and sure enough, it was null. How is this possible? @AymenDaoudi Are you sure? I have changed nothing from the Blank App template aside from those two snippets of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some quirks with resources and the `FindName` method in Windows Phones apps. And in this situation the problem is not tied to the `OnNavigatedTo`, `Loaded` or the other lifecycle events.

Before digging into the problem here a solution that works in all circumstances.  It uses the `ResourceDictionary` directly.

**Workaround**

```
// this will fail is some circumstances
btn.Style = TileStyle;

// this appears to work at any point in the 
// lifecycle, (assuming the style is in the Page.Resources element).
btn.Style = this.Resources["TileStyle"] as Style;
```

Now for some details.  Here is a simple repro that I used for testing.

**XAML**

```
<Page.Resources>
  <!-- FirstButtonStyle is defined 
        and accessed with the StaticResource
        markup extension. -->
  <Style x:Name='FirstButtonStyle'
          TargetType='Button'>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="0,0,0,0" />

  </Style>
  <!-- SecondButtonStyle is defined, 
        but not used -->
  <Style x:Name="SecondButtonStyle"
          TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="0,0,0,0" />
  </Style>


</Page.Resources>
  <StackPanel x:Name='MainPanel'>

    <Button x:Name="btn1"
            Style="{StaticResource FirstButtonStyle}"
            Content='Hello'
            Click='btn_Click' />
    <Button x:Name="btn2"
            Content='Hello'
            Click='btn_Click' />

  </StackPanel>
```

Windows Phone uses the `FindName` method, in the `InitializeComponent` method, to set a variable for each named element. You can see this code in the auto-generated file (in my case that's the file NullStylePage.g.i.cs located in the obj folder).

There are five named items in my XAML.  Here is the auto-generated code in `InitializeComponent`.

**Code**

```
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public void InitializeComponent()
{
    if (_contentLoaded)
        return;

    _contentLoaded = true;
    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(this, 
            new global::System.Uri("ms-appx:///NullStylePage.xaml"), global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ComponentResourceLocation.Application);

    FirstButtonStyle = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Style)this.FindName("FirstButtonStyle");
    SecondButtonStyle = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Style)this.FindName("SecondButtonStyle");
    MainPanel= (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel)this.FindName("MainPanel");
    btn1 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)this.FindName("btn1");
    btn2 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)this.FindName("btn2");
}
```

Put a breakpoint on the last line of this method and you can see which items are null. Since the `InitializeComponent()` method is marked with the `DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute` you'll need to turn off the **Enable Just My Code** option in Tools/Options to step through the code in the debugger.

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the Watch Window.

[image]

As you can see the value of `FirstButtonStyle` is null. The quirk is this.  When the style is not applied to an element (with the `StaticResource`), then the variable is instantiated correctly.  When the style is applied to any element, then the variable is `null`.

I'm not sure if this is a known bug but the workaround is to use the style from the Page.Resources.

```
 btn.Style = this.Resources["TileStyle"] as Style;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the page has not been fully constructed at the time of the OnNavigatedTo and so the assignment is not working. Try adding a Loaded event to the page and then perform the assignment in there instead.

Comment: How can that be possible, isn't the OnNavigatedTo supposed to execute after the construction ??!

Comment: After the class instance is created but before everything has been fully constructed on the page. For example, the DataContext will not be set in the OnNavigatedTo but will be set in the Loaded. I could be wrong, but I think it is worth trying out.

Comment: @PhilWright I added an event handler `PageLoaded` to the `Loaded` event in `OnNavigatedTo`, then pasted over the code... the Button is still not borderless. I did another `if (TileStyle == null)` check, and it still returns as null.